# How to swap stylesheets with a link

Tags: php, jquery, css, xhtml, mobile-website

I am developing a site using PHP, XHTML strict, and jQuery that will be flexible to support both mobile and desktop devices, using the [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) approach and serving different stylesheets using the min-device-width property.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 480px)" />
```

But the site will need to have a link to toggle the "desktop" and "moblie" view. I have a basic idea of how this could be done using jQuery, but would prefer a solution in **php** for devices that don't support JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP isn't too hard to implement this with.  If you were to use a link, like so...

```
<a href="?view=desktop">Desktop view</a>
```

Then in your page script...

```
//test for stylesheet parameter
if(isset($_GET['view']))
{
    //save and set it in the session
    $stylesheet = $_GET['view'];
    $_SESSION['stylesheet'] = $stylesheet;
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['stylesheet']))
{
    //parameter not sent, so get it from the session
    $stylesheet = $_SESSION['stylesheet'];
}
```

Later, you select your stylesheet code based on this `$stylesheet` variable.

```
if($stylesheet == 'desktop')
{
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desktop.css" type="text/css" />';
}
elseif($stylesheet == 'mobile')
{
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />';
}
else
{
    echo'<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 480px)" />';
}
```

Comment: The else would obviously be the current link stack using media queries.

Comment: This works aside from missing ")" characters in the if statements. -but I resolved that, and it's great.

Comment: Good catch on the missing ")", I suck at counting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, why not just include the appropriate stylesheet depending on a query parameter, or session variable or UA etc etc

```
//Code that figures out what type is 
$css  = '';
switch ($type) {
   case 'mobile':
       $css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" type="text/css" />';
       break;

    case 'touch':
       $css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960-mobile.css" type="text/css" />';
       break;

    case 'desktop':
    default:
       $css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960-full.css" type="text/css" />';
       break;
}
```

In your view

```
echo $css;
```

**NOTE** This is only an example. Ideally you shouldn't be constructing your whole link html in PHP, but not knowing any of your implementation details, it will suffice. Best way to do it would be to name your CSS files in a standard manner with only a `-type` at the end to differentiate where each file is used and just pass the `$type` variable to the view.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Why would you include the media queries in your switch of links? This would just cause the "forced" link to be ignored. Unles you are suggesting he also include user agent sniffing (blech).

Comment: @Kevin, Totally agree about the media queries, missed that :S  Edited

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SESSION variable for that. The following example assumes there are two stylesheets mobile.css and desktop.css

Testing the argument, and setting up the session.

```
 <?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['style']))//Tests the argument
    {
     if($_GET['style']=="desktop")//This to prevent passing wrong arguments
     {
      $_SESSION['style']=$_GET['style'];
     }
    if($_GET['style']=="mobile")//This to prevent passing wrong arguments
     {
      $_SESSION['style']=$_GET['style'];
     }
    }

    ?>

<head>
blah
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['style'])
{
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$_SESSION['style'].'.css" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
?>
</head>
```

Your link to switch from/to desktop CSS.

```
<a href="?style=desktop">Desktop version</a>
<a href="?style=mobile">Mobile version</a>
```